# need to find out where the function is instantiated (gcc 4.7)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-construction, linker

I compile and link a third-party library with GCC 4.7.3. I try understand what triggers the undefined symbol error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "void MyObject::myFunction<....>(...) const", referenced from:
     void NameSpace::AnotherFunction<some_particular_arguments>(...) in some_source.cc.o
```

`NameSpace::AnotherFunction` is obviously sitting in `some_source.cc`, but can I get some info from compiler/linker on where/who instantiate this function with `some_particular_arguments`?

The build is done using CMake and there is `NameSpace_AnotherFunction.inst` with template instantiations for the corresponding function, but this particular set of template arguments is not there.

Obviously there are no instantiations in `some_source.cc`, otherwise i would not ask ;)

Thus I wonder if there is a way to get info on something like Point of Instantiation (or similar) for that particular template arguments list of the function `AnotherFunction`?

Comment: find in files ?, this will work if the instance that uses the function is in visible code. If it's on a library that needs another library then you need some library inspection tool to find references to it.

Comment: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" looks like linker message which recognizes unsupported architecture. May it be, that the template argument you provide, is not available for x86_64?

Comment: @Raxvan i tried to find it in files, but don't see it. The function is a function of the library and should not need another one.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz I would say the MyObject::MyFunction was NOT indeed instantiated for the particular arguments. However, i am trying to find out where is the parent function instantiated (with those template parameters), and thought there might be some tools/command line options to facilitate it

Answer (score 1):

First compile with the -g flag to get an object file with source file and line number information for each symbol. Then use the [nm](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) command with -C and -l options on the object file to print out the symbol info, grepping for AnotherFunction. This should give you the line numbers.

**Edit:** Now that I have had a chance to try this out, I don't think it solves @Denis's problem. Unfortunately the line given is the line on which the function template is defined rather than the line on which it is instantiated. Leaving this answer here anyway in case it is useful to someone else...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to cause a compiler error (or better a warning) in the code that depends on the template type (so it is only emitted when the template is actually instantiated).

You can try making it more focused by doing something like

```cpp
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, some_particular_argument>())
    // code emitting warning
```